# Get Postgres Database Statistics via Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, monitoring

There's a database up, from which I need to monitor statistics.

**dbhandler.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(DBURL, {
   dialect : 'postgres',
    pool: {
       max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 1
    }
});
```

I am doing CRUD in this database via a node app. An example:

**osmetrics.js**

```
const osutils = require('os-utils');
const osu = require('node-os-utils');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const cpu = osu.cpu;

const dbMethods = require('../api/dbhandler');

const selectOsMetrics = async (limiter) => {
    const data = await dbMethods.osModel.findAll({limit: limiter, raw: true});

    let os_JSONlogs = { "success":true , "message":`Last ${limiter} records in database` };
    let arrayLogs = [];

    for(let entry of data)
    {
        arrayLogs.push(entry);
    }
    os_JSONlogs.data = arrayLogs;

    return os_JSONlogs;
};
```

And it works great.

On PGAdmin4 I can see there is statistics table available. "Database" => "Statistics" tab.

I would like to get the statistic in the node application, possibly via a method of the sequelize instance, but I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone I found useful pg stat queries in the following gist:
https://gist.github.com/anvk/475c22cbca1edc5ce94546c871460fdd